# ./config returns libcurl error

Tags: ubuntu, configure

When i try to install R 3.3. on my linux, using:

```
./config
```

It returns me the next error

```
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

IN the folder i see some makefiles but make or make check dosent work.
I checked and i have installed the last vertion of libcurl3, i use Ubuntu Based Peppermint 7.
Appreciate any help.

Kevin

Comment: I say this a lot, but why are you not using your distribution's binaries? Note also that if the versions for your distribution is not recent enough, Dirk supplies binaries via CRAN. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Oh, and your error probably means you need to install libcurl-dev and possibly also libcurl of the version mentioned. But I really wouldn't mess with this unless you want to.

Comment: @FaheemMitha  Hi, i didn't quite get what does it mean using my distro binaries :L , before posting the questions i try to search for the answer in the link that you posted but didn't worked for me.  Best

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about using your distribution binary packages. `apt-get install r-recommended` will install a basic R distribution for you. You don't have to compile from source.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Im new at using linux, yes I do that before, but it was installed the R 3.2. wooden Xmas tree version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `libcurl-dev` to get the development libraries and headers.

Depending on the version of of the OS this might be called by different names; see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libcurl-dev for details.

Comment: It worked!! im not shure what I actually did installing libcurl-ocam. At last i have the R 3.3. working on my linux!, (I was deppending on my windows pc because of this)