# configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https

Tags: centos, curl, libraries, header-file

Hi I met an issue when I tried to configure for R installation. 
Basically, I tried to follow my [previous installation process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343452/how-to-install-r-3-3-1-in-my-own-directory-issue-solved),
(For some reason, I need to reinstall the same R in CentOS6 instead of CentOS5)

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-3.3.2 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.47.1/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include -I/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.47.1/include"

configure exited because:

```
...
checking for curl-config... /u32/myusername/Programme/curl-7.52.1/bin//curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.52.1
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

noticed someone used and "7.47.1" it seemed to work for him/her, 
so installed "7.47.1", but it did not work. 
http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/?p=315

```
checking for curl-config... /u32/myusername/Programme/curl-7.47.1/bin//curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.47.1
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

noticed someone suggested to install a "libcurl-devel" [./config returns libcurl error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299716/config-returns-libcurl-error)
so I downloaded: ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages/libcurl-devel-7.19.7-52.el6.x86_64.rpm
    installed and set the PATH for it.

```
checking for curl-config... /u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl-devel/usr/bin/curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.19.7
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

noticed that "checking libcurl version ... 7.19.7" I speculated that the "libcurl-devel" might be too old. 
so I installed "libcurl-devel-7.29.0-35.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm" (this is for CentOS7, I could not find CentOS6 version)

```
checking for curl-config... /u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/bin//curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.29.0
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the output of `$HOME/Programme/curl-7.47.1/bin/curl-config --features`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer that got downvoted for some reason is completely right: `.configure` will produce a log file `config.log`, which will show the details of the `checking if libcurl supports https` test (most likely via an attempt to compile a given program).

Look at this log file, find out if your version of `libcurl` really doesn't support http, or if there is some other problem (e.g. missing/wrong library or include paths, or wrong library order, or trouble with your gcc variant, or changes in the library). In the latter case, fix the problem, possibly in `configure.in` or the equivalent, possibly by adding more options to the ones you already have, or changing the order of the libraries, or using a different gcc version.

In the former case, since you compiled `libcurl` yourself, make sure it's configured correctly and does support https.

I've done similar things on multiple occasions when self-compiling stuff.

You won't find "official sources" on this, that's just basic developing technique. You can easily convince yourself that the log file contains more detailed information by looking at it. It's a bit verbose, search for the `checking if libcurl` string to see the important part.

Randomly installing different versions of libraries without knowing what's wrong is not going to help.

Comment: I did not downvote the other answer, but it also wasn't clear what I should be looking for in the config.log from that answer, and new versions of gcc didn't seem to do anything. Yours was much clearer and it worked. Bounty awarded as soon as I can

Comment: The information what was actually wrong and what you did to fix it would also be interesting; possibly someone else is having the same problem. All I did was point out where to look. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure my situation is applicable :). I'm not on Centos and it was a mix of several things. A missing rtmpdump library, an older gcc version and then it was looking for a *.so.1 file when the compile required a *.so.0 file, so I soft linked the .1 file to the .0, installed the library, and then this monster: `./configure --prefix=/opt/R/3.3.3/ --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no --with-x=no CC=gcc-5 LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -lcurl"` ended up working for me. (Some of that is probably not necessary.. but far be it for me to remove an appendix from a healthy body)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem as yours. The real error message is in your config.log file.
Find that out and try to solve that. In my case, I changed another version of gcc to solve the problem.